# Drones compatible with ROS

Tags: ros, drone, parrot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone,
I'm currently looking a drone compatible with ROS and i need some buying advice. Currently i was working with a parrot bebop, coupled with a S.L.AM.Dunk also from Parrot. but it's not available anymore. [link of the S.L.A.M.Dunk.](https://www.parrot.com/fr/solutions-pro/parrot-slamdunk#parrot-slamdunk)
Therefore, i'm looking for a new drone, easily compatible with ROS and having at least the same specs that the SLAM (at least 2gb of ram memory, 16gb of memory, ubuntu embedded, openCV compatible etc..
I was thinking about the dji m100 coupled with the dji manifold and guidance but it's not cheap ! what do you think about it ? is there any other options ?

(PS : i also need a stereo camera or anything able to output a point cloud !)

Thank by advance !

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/279688/drones-compatible-with-ros/) by [StanSmooth](https://answers.ros.org/users/32748/stansmooth/) on ROS Answers with karma: 62 on 2018-01-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I can't give you any specific advice (hopefully someone else here can), but I can tell you where to look for more info.

If you want to find out what aerial drones are *officially* supported by ROS, I suggest you check out the [ROS Robots](http://robots.ros.org/) page, and specifically the [ROS Aerial Robots](http://robots.ros.org/category/aerial/) page. This page might need to be updated as it looks like [Erle-Copter](http://erlerobotics.com/blog/erle-copter/) and [DJI](https://github.com/dji-sdk/Onboard-SDK-ROS) now have official/semi-official support for ROS as well.

For more unofficial support, I suggest you read a [similar question](https://answers.ros.org/question/224557/ros-programmable-dronesuavs-in-the-market/) already here on ROS Answers and read through the [ROS news section](http://www.ros.org/news/robots/uavs/).

In general though, I'd always recommend using an officially supported ROS robot over an unofficially supported one. Using ROS code provided by the platform manufacturers will almost always be easier and less stressful to use than code written by yourself or a third party.

---

Originally posted by [M@t](https://answers.ros.org/users/26592/m@t/) with karma: 2327 on 2018-01-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [StanSmooth](https://answers.ros.org/users/32748/stansmooth/) on 2018-01-15**:
Thank you for your answer. the Erlecopter seems to be a good alternative for my project (besides the fact it doesn't have Lidar or Stereo camera on it), and i hope i will have some review about this drone !